# skill-sample-nodejs-fact-en-US returning more than 1 fact at a time

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Just playing around with the space fact example skill - is there anyway of returning more than 1 fact at a time?

I am guessing i would need to modify this part of the code but not a 100% sure. Still new to this.

```
handle(handlerInput) {
        const randomFact = cookbook.getRandomItem(data);
        const speechOutput = GET_FACT_MESSAGE + randomFact;
```

Thanks

---

[Code example on github](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact/blob/en-US/lambda/custom/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

The `data` array has the list of facts and `cookbook.getRandomItem(data)` returns a random fact from the `data` array. If you want to return two facts you have to get two random facts. So you will have to call `cookbook.getRandomItem(data)` twice to return the second random fact. When you call it for second time make sure that it doesn't return the same fact again.

```
handle(handlerInput) {
    const randomFact1 = cookbook.getRandomItem(data);
    var index1 = data.indexOf(randomFact1); // find the index
    var randomFact2 = cookbook.getRandomItem(data); // second random fact
    var index2 = data.indexOf(randomFact2);
    // to find a non-repeating random fact
    if (index1 == index2 ) {
      if(index2 == data.length-1) { //index2 is the last index
        randomFact2 = data[index2-1];
      } else {
        randomFact2 = data[index2+1];
      }
    } 
    const speechOutput = '<s>' + GET_FACT_MESSAGE + randomFact1 + '</s>' +
                         '<s> here is another one: '+ randomFact2 + '</s>';
    console.log(data);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .withSimpleCard(SKILL_NAME, randomFact1 + '\n \n' + randomFact2)
   }
```

May not be the best way to do it. But it works.